# Изображение и иконки в safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, кроссбраузерность

всем привет подскажите пожалуйста у меня safari ломает изображение

```
<img src="http://localhost:3011/uploads/Icon18.png" alt="">
```

а  когда меняю стили руками оно появляются что за поведение ? в других браузерах все ок !! как мне с этим бороться ????  при чем это происходит рандомно )) использую react

стили избражение

```
 width: 68.8px;
 height: 68.8px;
 object-fit: cover;
```

стили блока

```
border: 1px dashed #000000;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 5px;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
```

полная верстка

```
<div class="info-logo"><img src="http://localhost:3011/uploads/Icon18.png" alt=""></div>
```

как ломает изображение и версия Safari

safari
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

google
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можешь фото показать, как ломает ? и какая версия сафари ?

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Comment: кеши/историю чистил ? еще советуют: Try going to Safari/Preferences/Privacy and uncheck Prevent cross-site tracking. Quit/reopen Safari and test.

Comment: Не помогло есть еще варианты?

Comment: `.info-logo {display: flex;} .info-logo img {align-self: start;}`

Comment: спасибо большое display: flex; помог мне просто добавил одно свойство

Comment: отлично, тогда закроем тему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex;` на родителе - решает проблему

Comment: Можете описать ответ более подробно?